# How to connect to SQL Server with pyodbc and and sqlalchemy

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I've got problem with connection string to connect to SQL Server.

Now I have:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
drv='ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'
con_string=f'mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{passwd}@{server_ip}:1433/{db_name}?driver={drv}'
con=create_engine(con_string)
```

and I get an error

> pyodbc.OperationalError Login timeout expired

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I'm doing this from Ubuntu

Comment: Since you're using the URL format have you tried `ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server`? Because you're using ODBC Driver 18, and it has a breaking change that defaults to `Encrypt=yes`, you might also want to include either `TrustServiceCertificate=yes` or `Encrypt=no`.

Comment: Can you ping the server_ip?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQLAlchemy's URL object to build the connection string for you, e.g.:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="YourUsername",
    password="YourPassw0rd",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=1433,
    database="ExampleDb",
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
        "Encrypt": "yes",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
    },
)
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. Completely no idea what's wrong. One remark: I'm trying connect from Ubuntu. Howewer it seems it shouldn't be any different.

Comment: @data_b77 I'm currently connecting from Docker containers on a macOS host so, no, Ubuntu isn't the problem. Have you confirmed that the SQL Server is actually listening on tcp/1433? From Ubuntu can you `telnet server 1433` and get a successful connection?